# Extend joi-date to Joi module in Typescript

Tags: typescript, joi

I would like to add [@joi/date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@joi/date) to [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)

According to the JavaScript guide from the [official guide](https://joi.dev/module/joi-date/), extending the **joi** is given below

```
const Joi = require('joi').extend(require('@joi/date'));
```

**How to change this to TypeScript import way?**

typescript-eslint [says](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.20.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md),

> Require statement not part of import statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import BaseJoi from 'joi';
import JoiDate from '@joi/date';
const Joi = BaseJoi.extend(JoiDate);
```